# Does the order of route matter?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following routes.

```
<Route path='/route/:id/other' component={MyLayout} >
    <IndexRoute component={Form} />
    <Route path='me' component={Form} />
    <Route path='nothing' component={NothingComponent} />
    <Route path='something' component={SomethingComponent} />
</Route>
```

Inside `MyLayout` component I use the `childRoutes` to get the current step number of a flow, which is done using the following.

```
routes[0].childRoutes.forEach((route, index) => { 
    if (route.path === currentStep) { 
        currentStep = index + 1;
    } 
});
```

Then I use this to show a message of this format `1 of 3`, where `1` designates the step and is generated by the above script. Right now it takes into account the order of the `childRoutes` and presents invalid results e.g. `2 of 3` instead of `1 of 3`.

Does the order of the routes affect this?

0 = `<Route path='me' ...`

1 = `<Route path='nothing' ...`

2 = ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the order your write your routes reflects the order they are added in the route list when rendered.

```
<Route path='/route/:id/other' component={MyLayout} >
    <IndexRoute component={Form} />
    <Route path='me' component={Form} />                       = 0
    <Route path='nothing' component={NothingComponent} />      = 1
    <Route path='something' component={SomethingComponent} />  = 2
</Route>
```